# Give an example sentence: (Correct?)

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-usage, writing

Is this sentence correct?

> Give an example sentence:

I'm not sure whether there is a phrase ' example sentence' or not.

I always use:

> Give an example:

or

> Give a sentence as an example:

or

> other better sentences?

What would be the best way to ask someone to provide me with a sentence as en example?

Answer (score -1):

"Give an exemplary sentence" or "Give a sentence as an example" are correct.